# State Design pattern and infinite loops with MonoGame

Tags: c#, design-patterns, monogame, state-pattern

I am trying to use state design pattern with my game(MonoGame game).I want to detect collision , so I give cell type and upon it gives me a specific action.But unfortunately this implementation gives infinite loop "Exception.StackOverflow" in player instances.

```
     abstract class PlayerState
     {
         abstract public void doAction(Player player );
     }
```

Classes implements PlayerState

```
    class DeadState:PlayerState
    {
       public override void doAction(Player player)
            {
               player.dead();
               player.setState(this);
            }
     }

     class IncreaseGold: PlayerState
     {
    public override void doAction(Player player)
           {
               player.increaseGold();
               player.setState(this);
           }
     }
```

Player.cs

```
      public void setState(PlayerState state) { this.state = state; }
      public PlayerState getState() { return state; }
```

ActionController.cs

```
     Player player = new Player();

    public void passCell(int cellType)
    {
        if (cellType == 1)
        {
            new DeadState().doAction(player);
        }
        if (cellType == 2)
        {
            new IncreaseGold().doAction(player);
        }
    }
```

finally in my Update method on Game1.cs

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
       player.passCell(cellType);

       base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: When this infinity loop happen ?

Comment: The if in your controller where you basically switch over state types means that your implementation is wrong as this is something the state patterns is about to avoid.